# How to start a new chapter at right hand side in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, chapters

I have read the manual and try the

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [page=right]
```

but it has no effect :-(

Comment: You need to enable doublesided layout for this to work. `\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably use a single-page layout. Right pages only make sense in double-sided layouts. The following works here:

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [page=right]

\starttext
  \startsectionlevel [title=Foo]
  \stopsectionlevel

  \startsectionlevel [title=Bar]
  \stopsectionlevel
\stoptext
```

Alternatively you can define a custom page break with [\definepagebreak](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definepagebreak). Example:

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided]

\definepagebreak
  [chapterpagebreak]
  [yes, right]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [pagebreak=chapterpagebreak]

\starttext
  \startsectionlevel [title=Foo]
  \stopsectionlevel

  \startsectionlevel [title=Bar]
  \stopsectionlevel
\stoptext
```

Comment: I used single-page layout:-(  Thanks, now I will remember this forever :-)